# How to combine draws in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am writing code in Android Studio using Kotlin. I want to add both the DrawPixel and the DrawText in the same app. I keep trying to combine my code, but it wont work together.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.view.View
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val layout1 : ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout1)

        val background = Draw (this)
        layout1.addView (background)
    }

    class Draw (context: Context): View (context) {

        override fun onDraw (canvas: Canvas) {
            canvas.drawRGB (0, 0, 255)
            val height = getHeight ()
            val path = Path ()
            path.moveTo (100f, (height / 2) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (400f, (height / 2 - 30) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (800f, (height / 2 - 60) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (1200f, (height / 2 - 90) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (1600f, (height / 2 - 120) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (2200f, (height / 2 - 150) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (2800f, (height / 2 - 180) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (3400f, (height / 2 - 210) .toFloat ())

            val brush1 = Paint ()
            brush1.setARGB (255, 255, 0, 0)
            brush1.setTextSize (80f)
            canvas.drawTextOnPath ("AYOOOOOO", path, 300f, 30f, brush1)
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code for my DrawText in the MainActivity

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout


class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity (){

    override fun onCreate (savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState)
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main)

        val layout1 : ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout1)
        val background = Draw (this)
        layout1.addView(background)
    }

    class Draw (context: Context): View(context) {

        override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
            canvas.drawRGB(0,0,0)
            val width = getWidth()
            val height = getHeight()
            val paint = Paint()
            paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)
            for(x in 1..10000) {
                var x = (Math.random() * width).toFloat()
                var y = (Math.random() * height).toFloat()
                canvas.drawPoint(x, y , paint)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my code for the DrawPixel. I want to combine them both into the same screen but I don't know how. My intial thought was to make the MainActivity code this, but I know it's not right.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Path
import android.view.View
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val layout1 : ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout1)

        val background = Draw (this)
        layout1.addView (background)
    }

    class Draw (context: Context): View (context) {

        override fun onDraw (canvas: Canvas) {
            canvas.drawRGB (0, 0, 255)
            val height = getHeight ()
            val path = Path ()
            path.moveTo (100f, (height / 2) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (400f, (height / 2 - 30) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (800f, (height / 2 - 60) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (1200f, (height / 2 - 90) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (1600f, (height / 2 - 120) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (2200f, (height / 2 - 150) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (2800f, (height / 2 - 180) .toFloat ())
            path.lineTo (3400f, (height / 2 - 210) .toFloat ())

            val brush1 = Paint ()
            brush1.setARGB (255, 255, 0, 0)
            brush1.setTextSize (80f)
            canvas.drawTextOnPath ("AYOOOOOO", path, 300f, 30f, brush1)

            canvas.drawRGB(0,0,0)
            val width = getWidth()
            val height = getHeight()
            val paint = Paint()
            paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)
            for(x in 1..10000) {
                var x = (Math.random() * width).toFloat()
                var y = (Math.random() * height).toFloat()
                canvas.drawPoint(x, y , paint)
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to achieve? And what exactly is it that doesn't work in your third code example?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code, it's the order you're doing the operations in. Also, your code needs a bit of refactoring to work more efficiently.

Here

```
canvas.drawTextOnPath ("AYOOOOOO", path, 300f, 30f, brush1)

canvas.drawRGB(0,0,0) //here
```

after you've drawn the text, you're drawing `black` color on the `canvas`, which is drawing on the top of the `text` you've drawn earlier. It's making your `text` go away. Instead of drawing canvas background after drawing text, do it before any other `draw` operation.

```
class Draw(context: Context) : View(context) {

    private val path = Path()
    private val paint = Paint()
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0) //draw background here
        path.moveTo(100f, (height / 2).toFloat())
        path.lineTo(400f, (height / 2 - 30).toFloat())
        path.lineTo(800f, (height / 2 - 60).toFloat())
        path.lineTo(1200f, (height / 2 - 90).toFloat())
        path.lineTo(1600f, (height / 2 - 120).toFloat())
        path.lineTo(2200f, (height / 2 - 150).toFloat())
        path.lineTo(2800f, (height / 2 - 180).toFloat())
        path.lineTo(3400f, (height / 2 - 210).toFloat())

        paint.reset()
        paint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0)
        paint.textSize = 80f
        canvas.drawTextOnPath("AYOOOOOO", path, 300f, 30f, paint)

        paint.reset()
        paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)
        for (x in 1..10000) {
            val x = (Math.random() * width).toFloat()
            val y = (Math.random() * height).toFloat()
            canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint)
        }
    }
}
```

---

About the refactoring, `Paint` and `Path` are very expensive objects, you should never create them in the `onDraw()` method. Instead, create a global object of `Paint()` and reuse it as much as possible. `Paint` and `Path` have the `reset` method which sets them to their default settings.

`height` and `width` are already available in the `onDraw()` method, using their `property access syntax`, you can directly use them using their property name, instead of assigning them to a new variable named `height` or `width`.

I've refactored your code making these changes too.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do. I appreciate the explanation.